# Custom category attributes are not getting set

Tags: attributes

I have created a custom category attribute in my install script by using:

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_category',
    'my_custom_attribute',
    array(
        'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
        'group' => 'Custom Attributes',   
        'type'  => 'int',
        'class' => 'validate-number',
        'required' => false,
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'       => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true, 
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

This works fine, the category attribute is created in the database.
Now, I want to set the attribute to a specific value in a stand alone script:

```
    <?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app('default'); 
    umask(0);

    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(5); //category EAV
    $process->reindexAll();  // Re-index 

    $cat = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(1);

    $cat->setData('my_custom_attribute',   10);

    $cat->save();

    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(5); //category EAV
    $process->reindexAll();  // Re-index 

    $cat = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(1);

    $val = $cat->getData('my_custom_attribute');

    var_dump($val); // NULL <- should be 10
```

I have tried many different variations of setting / getting the value. As you can see I am re-indexing twice because we are using Flat Data.

I have been trying to work this out for ages - how do I simply set the custom attribute value so I can re-call it in the same script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of fiddling and playing - I asked a colleague. We're not sure why this works though. But here you go:

```
    <?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app('admin');  <-- THIS LINE from 'default' to 'admin'
    umask(0);

    // ......
```

Painful.